# Stop img tags from flickering when re-rendering with JavaScript

Tags: html, css, webkit, web

Our web app is built entirely in JS.
To make it snappy we cache resources (models) between page views and reload the resource when you view a page.

Our flow is like this:

1. The user is in ViewA
2. The user switches to ViewB
3. We use the cached resource to render ViewB
4. We start a fetch for resource
5. When the resource is fetched we render again

This has a nasty drawback of causing `<img>` tags to flicker, ever if they are the same.
The problem is that `Backbone.js`, which we use, doesn't tell us if anything changed when fetching a collection, just that it was fetched.

Here's a quick demo of what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/p7DdG/
It only happens in webkit and with `<img>` tags, not with background images as you can see.

We think it's kinda ugly to use `background-image` instead of a proper `img` tag.

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Are you doing each `$('img').replaceWith` yourself?

Comment: Not seeing any flicker in Chrome.

Comment: All the parent containers are removed and created by me. I'm using Chrome 18.0.1025.39 beta

Comment: It seems like it is a Chrome (osx - not tested windows) bug - couldn't find any other solution then background-images so for now it's the only fix I'm afraid - ugly or not at least it works :)

Comment: They've fixed it now, problem solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is gone in Chrome 19, problem solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing exactly how the URL of each image is being built I'm not certain this will work, but could you check the src attribute of each image tag against the one you are replacing it with before doing the replace?
e.g.

```
 var newImageSrc = "http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png";
 if (newImageSrc != $("img").attr("src")) {
    $('img').replaceWith('<img src="'+newImageSrc +'">');
 }
```

Alternatively - load the image offscreen, and attach an event handler to the onload event of the image, which moves the image to the current image's parent tag, and remove the old one.
e.g.

```
var oldImage = $("#oldImageId");
var newImageSrc = "http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png";
var newImage = new Image();
$(newImage).load(function (event) {
    $(oldImage).parent().append(newImage);
    $(oldImage).detach();
});
$(newImage).attr("src", newImageSrc);
```

Comment: This will not work as I'm replacing a root element which contains all the images. Since the order of the images might have changed or an image might have been added/deleted I cannot simply iterate and replace when needed.

Comment: The only other option I can think of then would be to load the image into a new tag off screen, then move it into the other image's parent.  I'll put up some sample code...

Comment: If you put up the actual code you are using perhaps we could take a look and come up with something without this back and forth then ;)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and noticed that sometimes images do flicker and sometimes don't. Even in latest Chrome (v33 as of now).

For posterity, **flickering happens with uncached images**.

In my case, `Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000` totally eliminated it.